# How to order queryset with lookup fields?

Tags: django, django-views, django-queryset

I want to order my users with their full_name from profile model. How can I do it here ?

views

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('profile.full_name')
```

models

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You look "through" a relation with double underscores (`__`), so you can order with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(is_active=True).order_by('profile__full_name')
```

This will make a JOIN in the database, and thus order on the `full_name` field of the related `profile`.